# Putting an image inside a basic trapezoid done with pure CSS?

Tags: css, html

Is there a way to put the image on the top inside the red area on the bottom?

I tried different combinations with no success.

Could you provide a JSFiddle with a working code?

[image]

```css
#rectangle {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url('https://image.ibb.co/e5Kaw7/image.png');
  background-size: contain;
}
#trapezoid {
    border-top: 100px solid red;
    border-left: 100px solid transparent;
    border-right: 100px solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="rectangle"></div>
<br />
<div id="trapezoid"></div>
```

My purpose is to build a frame. So I'm gonna do this 4 times (for each edge). But if I know how to do it for the top edge I could do it for the rest.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`clip-path` might come in handy.

```css
#rectangle {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url('https://image.ibb.co/e5Kaw7/image.png');
  background-size: contain;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, calc(100% - 100px) 100%, 100px 100%);
}
```

```html
<div id="rectangle"></div>
```

Here's an attempt at a full frame:

```css
.any-picture {
  width: 450px;
  height: 120px;
  padding: 80px;
  background-color: #BADA55;
  background-clip: content-box;
}

picture-frame {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #20180e;
}

picture-frame f-t,
picture-frame f-b,
picture-frame f-r,
picture-frame f-l {
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(https://image.ibb.co/e5Kaw7/image.png);
  background-size: contain;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, calc(100% - 80px) 100%, 80px 100%);
  display: block;
}

picture-frame f-r,
picture-frame f-l {
  bottom: -80px;
  width: 280px;
}

picture-frame f-r {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: top right;
  right: 0;
}

picture-frame f-l {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  left: 0;
  transform-origin: top left;
}

picture-frame f-b {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<picture-frame>           <f-t>          </f-t>          <f-l>

</f-l>          <div class="any-picture"></div>          <f-r>

</f-r>          <f-b>         </f-b>          </picture-frame>
```

And, as long as you have the `width`, `height` and `frameWidth`, here's an  `SCSS` helper:

```css
$iWidth: 200px;
$iHeight: 150px;
$fWidth: 80px;
.any-picture {
  width: $iWidth;
  height: $iHeight;
  padding: $fWidth;
  background-clip: content-box;
}

picture-frame {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  f-t,f-b,f-r,f-l {
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url(https://image.ibb.co/e5Kaw7/image.png);
    background-size: contain;
    height: $fWidth;
    width: 100%;
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, calc(100% - #{$fWidth}) 100%, $fWidth 100%);
    display: block;
  }
  f-r,f-l {
    bottom: -$fWidth;
    width: $iHeight + 2*$fWidth;
  }
  f-r {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform-origin: top right;
    right: 0;
  }
  f-l {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    left: 0;
    transform-origin: top left;
  }
  f-b {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/a7xLjLu8/

To do it dynamically, one could use CSS `var(--iables)`

```css
body { margin-bottom: 0;}
:root {
  --img-width: calc(100vw - 146px);
  --img-height: calc(100vh - 146px);
  --frm-width: 65px;
  --img-bg: #BADA55;
  --frm-bg: #20180e;
}

.any-picture {
  width: var(--img-width);
  height: var(--img-height);
  padding: var(--frm-width);
  background-color: var(--img-bg);
  background-clip: content-box;
}

picture-frame {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: var(--frm-bg);
}

picture-frame f-t,
picture-frame f-b,
picture-frame f-r,
picture-frame f-l {
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(https://image.ibb.co/e5Kaw7/image.png);
  background-size: contain;
  height: var(--frm-width);
  width: 100%;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, calc(100% - var(--frm-width)) 100%, var(--frm-width) 100%);
  display: block;
}

picture-frame f-r,
picture-frame f-l {
  bottom: calc(var(--frm-width) * -1);
  width: calc(var(--img-height) + (2 * var(--frm-width)));
}

picture-frame f-r {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: top right;
  right: 0;
}

picture-frame f-l {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  left: 0;
  transform-origin: top left;
}

picture-frame f-b {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<picture-frame>           <f-t>          </f-t>          <f-l>

</f-l>          <div class="any-picture"></div>          <f-r>

</f-r>          <f-b>         </f-b>          </picture-frame>
```

Comment: that was awesome!